# What is the sql to query SqlServer system databases to find an DB object?

Tags: sql-server

I have a large db with many tables and sprocs, and I want to find and see, for example, if there is a table with a name that has "setting" as part of it.  I'm not very familiar with SqlServer's System Databases like master, msdb etc., I know there is a way to query one of those dbs to get what I need back, does someone know how to do it?

Thank you,
Ray.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server also supports the standard information schema views.  Probably better to use them, since this query should also work across different database engines if you ever need to do a migration:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables where table_name LIKE '%Settings%'
```

Answer (score 1):

the table you want is sys.objects

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.objects
```

Answer (score 0):

The table with the info you seek is called sysobjects.  Here's a query for what you describe:

```
SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype = 'U' AND NAME LIKE '%setting%'
```

(U is the type for user tables)

Comment: sysobjects is now depracated by MS. You should use sys.objects instead.

Answer (score 0):

For Sql Server 2005

SELECT * FROM sys.objects where type in ('U') and name like '%setting%'